# How to Store Chat Under Uid

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I'm creating a chat bot using `ai.apu`. I store chat data under firebase database and I also add google authentication in my app when user login my app, then I store user data such as name email and uid. But the problem is when User 1 is logged in to my app then they type `hii` for chat bot and chat bot reply for user it's `hello okk`. But when user 2 logs in to my app that able to read and write chat for user 1. It's same for all users. So I need help to how to store chat under uid.

Here is my code:

```
package smartudevelopers.co.in.ustudy;


import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

import java.util.Objects;

import ai.api.AIDataService;
import ai.api.AIListener;
import ai.api.AIServiceException;
import ai.api.android.AIConfiguration;
import ai.api.android.AIService;
import ai.api.model.AIRequest;
import ai.api.model.AIResponse;
import ai.api.model.Result;

public class Robot extends AppCompatActivity implements AIListener {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    EditText editText;
    RelativeLayout addBtn;
    DatabaseReference ref;
    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<ChatMessage,chat_rec> adapter;
    Boolean flagFab = true;
    private AIService aiService;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_robot);

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO},1);

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        editText = findViewById(R.id.editText);
        addBtn = findViewById(R.id.addBtn);

        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        final LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

        ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        ref.keepSynced(true);

        final AIConfiguration config = new AIConfiguration("0aa300312b0443dcb7eca07a7d020eaf",
                AIConfiguration.SupportedLanguages.English,
                AIConfiguration.RecognitionEngine.System);

        aiService = AIService.getService(this, config);
        aiService.setListener(this);

        final AIDataService aiDataService = new AIDataService(config);

        final AIRequest aiRequest = new AIRequest();



        addBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                String message = editText.getText().toString().trim();

                if (!message.equals("")) {

                    ChatMessage chatMessage = new ChatMessage(message, "user" );
                    ref.child("chat").push().setValue(chatMessage);

                    aiRequest.setQuery(message);
                    new AsyncTask<AIRequest,Void,AIResponse>(){

                        @Override
                        protected AIResponse doInBackground(AIRequest... aiRequests) {
                            final AIRequest request = aiRequests[0];
                            try {
                                final AIResponse response = aiDataService.request(aiRequest);
                                return response;
                            } catch (AIServiceException e) {
                            }
                            return null;
                        }
                        @Override
                        protected void onPostExecute(AIResponse response) {
                            if (response != null) {

                                Result result = response.getResult();
                                String reply = result.getFulfillment().getSpeech();
                                ChatMessage chatMessage = new ChatMessage(reply, "bot");
                                ref.child("chat").push().setValue(chatMessage);
                            }
                        }
                    }.execute(aiRequest);
                }
                else {
                    aiService.startListening();
                }

                editText.setText("");

            }
        });



        editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                ImageView fab_img = findViewById(R.id.fab_img);
                Bitmap img = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.ic_send_white_24dp);
                Bitmap img1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.ic_mic_white_24dp);


                if (s.toString().trim().length()!=0 && flagFab){
                    ImageViewAnimatedChange(Robot.this,fab_img,img);
                    flagFab=false;

                }
                else if (s.toString().trim().length()==0){
                    ImageViewAnimatedChange(Robot.this,fab_img,img1);
                    flagFab=true;

                }


            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });

        adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<ChatMessage, chat_rec>(ChatMessage.class,R.layout.msglist,chat_rec.class,ref.child("chat")) {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(chat_rec viewHolder, ChatMessage model, int position) {

                if (model.getMsgUser().equals("user")) {


                    viewHolder.rightText.setText(model.getMsgText());

                    viewHolder.rightText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    viewHolder.leftText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                else {
                    viewHolder.leftText.setText(model.getMsgText());

                    viewHolder.rightText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    viewHolder.leftText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }
        };

        adapter.registerAdapterDataObserver(new RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver() {
            @Override
            public void onItemRangeInserted(int positionStart, int itemCount) {
                super.onItemRangeInserted(positionStart, itemCount);

                int msgCount = adapter.getItemCount();
                int lastVisiblePosition = linearLayoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();

                if (lastVisiblePosition == -1 ||
                        (positionStart >= (msgCount - 1) &&
                                lastVisiblePosition == (positionStart - 1))) {
                    recyclerView.scrollToPosition(positionStart);

                }

            }
        });

        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);


    }
    public void ImageViewAnimatedChange(Context c, final ImageView v, final Bitmap new_image) {
        final Animation anim_out = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(c, R.anim.zoom_out);
        final Animation anim_in  = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(c, R.anim.zoom_in);
        anim_out.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener()
        {
            @Override public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}
            @Override public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}
            @Override public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation)
            {
                v.setImageBitmap(new_image);
                anim_in.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                    @Override public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}
                    @Override public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}
                    @Override public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {}
                });
                v.startAnimation(anim_in);
            }
        });
        v.startAnimation(anim_out);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResult(ai.api.model.AIResponse response) {


        Result result = response.getResult();

        String message = result.getResolvedQuery();
        ChatMessage chatMessage0 = new ChatMessage(message, "user");
        ref.child("chat").push().setValue(chatMessage0);


        String reply = result.getFulfillment().getSpeech();
        ChatMessage chatMessage = new ChatMessage(reply, "bot");
        ref.child("chat").push().setValue(chatMessage);


    }

    @Override
    public void onError(ai.api.model.AIError error) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAudioLevel(float level) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onListeningStarted() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onListeningCanceled() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onListeningFinished() {

    }
}
```

Comment: Is this related to JavaScript? Because I see a lot of Java code and those two aren't the same.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to set up a separate child node for each user. Since you already added Google sign-in to your app, you can use [last signed-in account to determine the user ID](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/people), and use that to identify the chat node (often also called "room") for each user:

```
GoogleSignInAccount acct = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(getActivity());
if (acct != null) {
  String personId = acct.getId();
  ref.child("chat").child(personId).push().setValue(chatMessage);
}
```